# C++ output not showing in PHP

Tags: php, c++, g++

i have a small problem, i have a c++ program, but PHP is not showing output, only "blank". I made a small program to test, when I use "printf" and "gcc" to compile, it works fine, but when I compile the same progran using "g++" it fails to show the content in the php page. Any ideas? I can't use "gcc" because my project is in c++

I'm using this version of gcc/g++

g++ (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)

**EDIT:** I simplified the problem so you can understand what is going on here, thanks for your help. Now i get a missing library error.

I compiled the files using the followings commands:

```
gcc -o prueba1 prueba.c
g++ -o prueba2 prueba.cpp
```

So "prueba1" is the one compiled with GCC and "prueba2" is the one compiled with G++

Here is the file `test.php`

```
<?php
      echo "Executing file compiled with GCC <br />"; 
      echo shell_exec("./prueba1");
      echo "<br />";
      echo "Executing file compiled with G++ <br />";
      echo shell_exec("./prueba2 2>&1");
?>
```

I get this on the browser:

```
Executing file compiled with GCC
Hello World (GCC) 
Executing file compiled with G++
./prueba2: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
```

Here is the prueba.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argsv[]){

printf("Hello World (GCC)\n");

return(0);

}
```

Here is the prueba.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argsv[]){

cout << "Hello World (G++)" << endl;

return(0);

}
```

Comment: This question makes no sense.  You have some C++ source code, which you compile with GCC?  What does this have to with PHP?

Comment: You need to provide us with code.

Comment: please show the piece of **PHP** you use to call your external program.

Comment: When I run the executable in PHP is not showing nothing, it's like is ignoring C++ program at all, but when I try with a C program it works just fine. Here is the code I use, I also tried `exec`, `passthru`, etc. 

`<?php
echo shell_exec("./prueba 5 6");
?>`

Comment: what happens when you call the c++ program directly from the command line? where is the source? what are the compiler warnings you're getting?

Comment: @Pace: If you run the executable at the command-line (rather than from PHP), do you get the expected output?

Comment: Yes, i get the expected output in the command line, the problem is only in PHP

Comment: Do you get output if you use `shell_exec` with another command such as `ls`?

Comment: @GWW Yes, i get output with other Linux commands, I even get output from C executables compiled with "gcc" instead of "g++" the problem is my project is in C++, and it seems PHP is ignoring that kind of file

Comment: @Pace: PHP doesn't know whether you compiled with GCC or G++, so that cannot be the problem.

Comment: Your code is C, so I don't understand why you can't compile it with `gcc`.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth It works with file compiled with GCC, but with files compiled with G++ it doesn't, and is the same sourcecode, I think PHP is ignoring the one compiled with G++

Comment: @Pace: If there is no difference in results on the command-line, then there is no difference to PHP (which is only passing the command to the command-line). You've made a mistake somewhere else. And, again, PHP has _no idea_ what compiler you used; "PHP is ignoring the one compiled with g++" PHP does no such thing.

Comment: @Tomalak I know, this is just a test code to prove the problem. My C++ Project is a lot bigger, and I cannot translate it to C, this file "prueba.cpp" when I compile it using GCC, it works just fine in PHP, but using G++ returns nothing. I think PHP is ignoring the file or something

Comment: I edited the question to show the problem I'm getting, is really strange, but it seems like PHP is ignoring the one compiled with G++

Comment: @Pace: Repeating your fallacy over and over will not make it come true.

Comment: @Tomalak I know, i'm sorry, is just the only theory I have, please help me

Comment: @Mat: When I compile in the command line, both programs runs fine, and return the output

Comment: @Pace: I don't know what the problem is, but it will be nothing to do with C vs. C++, I guarantee it.  To simplify the problem, reduce your C/C++ source code to a single printf statement, and examine the raw PHP output, don't rely on an HTML browser.

Comment: @Oil I can reduce my program to printf statement, but the problem is, i have to compile it with G++ because my program is in C++ not C, and in the example above, when I do this, is not printing nothing

Comment: @Pace: I don't understand what you mean.  I'm suggesting that you simplify your situation, in order to find out where the problem is.

Comment: @Pace Your problem simply cannot be reproduced. Copying the above files and compiling them with gcc and g++ (using the same version as you) yields exactly the expected output. Try it yourself in a fresh directory. I doubt you’ll be able to reproduce the problem yourself.

Comment: @Konrad my problem is in PHP, not in C++, i'm using XAMPP

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you `shell_exec` the C++ program first ?

Comment: @Ugo Yes, I get the same result, C++ is not executing, but C is executing normally

Comment: Take a look at your error log (something like /var/log/httpd/error_log). It seems that unfortunately shell_exec returns nothing when an error occurs.

Comment: @Ugo: No, nothing in my error log is empty, don't know what else to do

Comment: ... Maybe check that permissions are the same for both binaries.

Comment: @Ugo: Yes, they are exactly the same, I even tried to change them to `777`

Comment: @Ugo: Really, it is, I need to get this done, the problem seems to be only with G++, probable is ignoring the file or just running background, don't know :S

Comment: if you add 2>&1 at the end of your command ? (in order to redirect stderr to standard output)

Comment: @Ugo: Excellent now I see the error, I updated my post, thx, let's find out

Comment: @Ugo: Still, where I can find those libraries? Do I need to update something? XAMPP is really new, I downloaded like a month ago

Comment: Well I have to go. But a quick fix is to prepend `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... ; ` to the command. With ... being the right library path (any usual path matching */lib/).

Comment: try calling c++ code without 2>&1

Comment: @Pace yes there is probably a problem with the setting of XAMPP. but anyway the lib is there since you can execute the binary in a shell. Just try to add hte right path to the good libgcc_s.so.1 exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH ...

Comment: @Pace Also try 'bash --login ./prueba2'

Comment: I renamed the `/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` to `/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1.back` it seems C++ was trying to access this one instead the one when I call it from the command line, now works fine, thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Rename the `/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` to `/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1.backup`, it seems C++ was trying to access this one instead the one that linux does when running from command line, thanks for the help guys